# Algorithms to copy a sub-tree in a node

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, optimization, tree

I have an application in nodejs and angular, which simulates being a directory of folders and files, I can create folders and files normally, up to n levels, now I want to be able to copy a folder from one directory to another folder with all its children, which algorithms or approaches to solve this problem.

As I work with mongodb, I am storing in a table node, folders and files

```
node{
id:
type: // folder or file,
parents: [list parents] // for breadcumb
childs: [list childs]
....
....
}
```

If I wanted to copy a sub-tree, I would have to make a recursive copy of all its nodes, which does not seem efficient because of the exponential complexity.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Either you copy, or you don't copy and re-link. But if you copy, then there will be number of elements that you need to touch that scales exponentially with the depth of the nested structure.

Comment: if I redirect, the nodes are not independent, and I want the nodes to be independent, to be able to edit the children of sub tree x, and that this does not edit the subhomes of the original tree.